# Clangd with compile_commands.json inside header files

Tags: c++, c, clang, neovim, language-server-protocol

I am using neovim with configured lsp (clangd) for a C project I'm working on. Whenever I'm inside a source `.c` file, the lsp works great and can locate definitions and stuff whether they're inside other source files or in one of the headers. However, the issue arises when I enter any header file. The LSP completely breaks and is not able to find almost any definitions. I figured that was due to the fact that `compile_commands.json` contains only entries for source files. So whenever I open a `.c` file, `clangd` knows which include paths and files to search for definitions. When I open a `.h` file, there is no corresponding entry inside `compile_commands.json` and `clangd` is completely lost.

My question is, what is the best way to fix this issue and get the LSP working properly when inside header files?

Also, I mentioned `neovim` since that is my use case, but the issue isn't (neo)vim specific. If anything it's specific to `clangd`, but I believe that all `compile_commands.json` based language servers have the same problem.

Comment: I know of that SE, but I opted for SO, since the issue is not really (neo)vim specific. It's more related to clangd and how `compile_commands.json` works in general. I added an edit to clarify that in the original question.